# Android Studio - Fragment onClickListener not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, onclicklistener

After reviewing every possible answer, I cannot find what's wrong with my code.

I need to have an OnClickListener on 3 fragments, one of them being loaded by the mainActivity. None of them are working. I have implemented the OnClickListener on each fragment.

Here's my code:

**RequestFragment1.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request1, container, false);
    Button buttonRequest1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Request1Button);
    buttonRequest1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "https://www.google.ca/";
            WebView httpRequestResult = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webViewResult);
            httpRequestResult.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
            httpRequestResult.loadUrl(url);
            getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.requests_webview);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**fragment_request1.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Request1Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Requête 1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_request1);

    View currentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    //Implementation du TouchListener
    currentView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeListener(MainActivity.this) {
```

It needs to open a webview by pressing Request1Button.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help you, we need some more information. What exactly do you want this app to do? What is it doing now? Also, it would help if you reduce the code to focus directly on your question. You can create a new Android Studio project for experimenting. Get this prototype app to work with a single listener. Then work from there.

Comment: p.s. Also remember that Java requires all code to be in classes. Including these class declarations gives us a better idea of the context of your code, especially in Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_request1);
```

This line in `MainActivity.onCreate()` inflates the layout defined in the XML file named `fragment_request1`. However, it does **not** create a fragment. Therefore, `RequestFragment1.onCreateView()` is never called and the `OnClickListener` is never set.

You need to properly create the fragment and load it with `FragmentManager`. There are many online tutorials that show how to do this. I suggest starting with the one on the Android Developer website.

Comment: You were right! I'll accept your answer once everything has been solved, but you were on the right track! Thank you!