# Java OnClickListener not working in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a simple click on a button in a `Fragment` but the event is ignored.

This is the code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View i =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id_upload, container, false);

    btn = i.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("data","ok clickled");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setMessage("hjgdfhfghfghf gfdgf");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });


    return i;
}
```

I don't know what is wrong in the code?

Comment: How does your `fragment_id_upload.xml`  look?

Comment: Try the above code in onViewCreated() instead of onCreateView(). And see if it works.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar still same problem

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: sorry stackoverflow asking more details

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar  ok  http://justnotepad.com/get/3a0983ddfbed30f2c2d1968aded9d23e   temp file

Comment: pass:- 12345678

Comment: Your layout is fine. Is there any exception or something related to error in your logcat when you open this fragment?

Comment: Is this answer helpful?https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926931/12182265

Comment: there no error in log

Comment: Can you post your activity and fragment related all code in this stack overflow thread?

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar problem solved by using `FragmentManager` thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please post answer if possible so that future readers can gather some information from this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I have fixed this by using `FragmentManager`

like :-

```
FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragment.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, fragment_id_upload.class,null).commit();


R.id.fragmentContainerView  //this is fragment container view
```

for more details:- go to  [Android Studio - Fragment onClickListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926804/android-studio-fragment-onclicklistener-not-working/41926931#41926931)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View i =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id_upload, container, false);

    btn = i.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("data","ok clickled");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
            builder.setMessage("hjgdfhfghfghf gfdgf");
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });


    return i;
}


Try requireActivity() instead of getActivity()
```

Comment: Instead of `requireActivity()` replace with `view.getContext()`